# Array of object with 3 properties with strong behavior in drawing a route in google maps API

Tags: arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to animate a marker along a route . the marker moves but the route isn't drawn (please, press "display" then "animate" button)  (my code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agr3a07m/162/)

The coordinates of the route are stored in the array of object" coord={lat: ,lng:, stop: } " which is filled in by the function below (I call it in line 208 in my code ):

```js
function getLatLng(point, array) {

    //alert(MyArray.length);

    var lat = point.lat(),
        lng = point.lng();
    var tmp = MyArray[count].split(",");
    //  alert(  Math.abs(parseFloat(tmp[0]- lat)) )
    if (Math.abs(parseFloat(tmp[0] - lat)) < 0.00009 && Math.abs(parseFloat(tmp[1] - lng)) < 0.00009) {
        count++;
        array.push({
            "lat": lat,
            "lng": lng,
            "stop": 1
        });
        
    } else {

        array.push({
            "lat": lat,
             "lng": lng,
             "stop": 0
        });
      
    }
}
```

Then I call the function 'h(coord)' in the line 212 which takes the coordinates array as parameter.

```js
function h(c) {
    //count++;
     alert( c.length +' '+ c);
    if (count == lengthCoord) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
                autoRefresh(map, c);
            });
        });

    }


}
```

Then I call the function autoRefresh to animate the marker.

```js
unction autoRefresh(map, f) {
    var i, route, marker;
    g = f;
    // alert(g[1]);
    route = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [],
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        editable: false,
        map: map
    });
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png"
    });
    var i = 0,
        j = 0;

    fi(map, marker, g);

    function fi(m, mar, l) {
        // for (i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
        var t = ["10", "200", "30 ", "40", "50", "60", "70", "80", "90", "100", "120", "130", "140", "150", ];
        k = i % 15;
        if (l[i].stop == 0) {
            //  alert(l[1].stop + '' + l[1 + 1].stop);
            setTimeout(function (coordo) {
                var latlng = coordo
              //  alert(latlng.lat);
                route.getPath().push(latlng);

                moveMarker(map, marker, latlng);
            }, 100 * i, l[i]);
            i++;
            fi(m, mar, l);
        } else {
            setTimeout(function (coordo) {
                var latlng = coordo
                route.getPath().push(latlng);

                moveMarker(map, marker, latlng);
                
            }, 100 * i, l[i]);



            setTimeout(fi, 600, m, mar, l);
            i++;
        }
    }

}
```

The 1 problematic is : the function h() should alert the coord object but i get anything.

The 2 problematic:In line 315, The function autoRefresh takes the object coord and store them in the polyline to draw route. It works even if the coord is an object { lat: , mng : ,stop } not type of (lat,lng).

The 3 problematic : The route isn't drawn.

I'm getting confused. 
could anyone explain me what is the problem ?

Thanks !

Comment: Your jsfiddle has issues.

Comment: could you know why does the route isn't drawn ?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I keep it simple Please check this Jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/agr3a07m/165/).
 Actually, I have an object coord ( line 195) which I pass to the function h()( Line 208). In this function I call another fucntion g() . It takes also the coord object as argument. When I comment line 211(  in order not to call g() ), It works but if I call the function g() I cannot obtain the alert.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because you took out the line 189 `directionsDisplay[instance].setDirections(response);`

Comment: Actually, I want to draw a route according to the mouvement of the marker. [This is a simple exemple of code I developed](http://jsfiddle.net/oynovzq4/38/ ).